# Error in Rshiny: "argument missing with no default"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm just starting to discover Rshiny and after a week playing with it I've tried to create a map where I could display only certain polygons thanks to the function "selectizeInput"...

I thought that I would manage to do that thanks to the script below but I'm actually getting the error "argument missing with no default" that I can't solve!

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please ?

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title ="Draft_1"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Map", tabName = "counties", icon = icon('info')),
    )
  ),
  


dashboardBody(
                      
tabItems(
                               
tabItem(tabName = "counties",
           fluidRow(selectizeInput("COUNTIES_ID", choices = shapefile1, selected="NONE"))
           ),
           
           fluidRow(leafletOutput("map-test", height = 500)),
           )))
  

server <- function(input, output){
  
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 
                      "COUNTIES_ID",
                      choices = shapefile1,
                      options = list(maxOptions = 1000),
                      selected = "45FDG)
  
  output$map-test<-renderLeaflet(
    leaflet(shapefile1) %>%
      setView(1.45, 43.52, zoom = 12) %>%
      addTiles()  %>% 
      addPolygons(fillColor = "blue",
                  weight = 2,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.3,
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 5,
                    color = "#666",
                    dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.7,
                    bringToFront = TRUE),
                  layerId = ~COUNTIES_ID)
  )}
  
  
  


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but you're missing a closing quotation in your `updateSelectizeInput` after `45FDG`. It should be "45FDG" not "45FDG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `,` at the end of :

```
sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Map", tabName = "counties", icon = icon('info')),
    )
```

This `,` makes `sidebarMenu` expect another Item which it doesn't find.

Comment: Thanks Waldi, sorry for the silly question ! :(

Now I have a new error message: "no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector". Does it mean my shapefile is too big and I shall use a .RDS file instead ?

Comment: Difficult to tell because you didn't provide definition for shapefile1. However, I doubt that you can use shapefile1 as choice  for `selectizeInput("COUNTIES_ID", choices = shapefile1, selected="NONE")` and as `leaflet(shapefile1)`